# How to delete environment variables using Ansible

Tags: regex, ansible

I want to delete below environment variables from etc/environment using Ansible.

export http_proxy="http://194.138.0.25:9400/"

export https_proxy="http://194.138.0.25:9400/"

export ftp_proxy="http://194.138.0.25:9400/"

Below code deletes only one env variable.

- name: Delete variables from etc/environment

  ```
  replace: 
    path: /etc/environment
    regexp: 'export http_proxy="http://194.138.0.25:9400/"'
    replace: ''
  ```

1. How to delete all the 3 environment variables?
2. After deleting/replacing any one env variable, empty line is being added. how to avoid this?

Comment: Please read a regexp tutorial and edit your question with a proposition for your regexp that shows you at least made some effort to solve your issue by yourself. As is your question is barely asking "please write my regexp for me" as you pasted a totally fixed string which will match a single possibility (which totally blows-up the purpose of using a regexp). If you don't know where to start https://regex101.com/ is a pretty good reference. Regarding your second point (new lines left in file), you should look at `lineinfile` with `state: absent` which is better suited for your purpose.

Comment: your right, thank you, I will go through the link.

Answer (score 2):

Use [lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html#ansible-builtin-lineinfile-module-manage-lines-in-text-files). For example, the task below will remove all lines starting `export` and including the address `194.138.0.25:9400/`

```yaml
    - lineinfile:
        path: /tmp/environment
        regex: '^export.*194\.138\.0\.25:9400.*$'
        state: absent
```

Given the file

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/environment 
first line
export http_proxy="http://194.138.0.25:9400/"
export https_proxy="http://194.138.0.25:9400/"
export ftp_proxy="http://194.138.0.25:9400/"
last line
```

Running the playbook with options --check --diff gives (abridged)

```yaml
TASK [lineinfile] ***************************************************
--- before: /tmp/environment (content)
+++ after: /tmp/environment (content)
@@ -1,5 +1,2 @@
 first line
-export http_proxy="http://194.138.0.25:9400/"
-export https_proxy="http://194.138.0.25:9400/"
-export ftp_proxy="http://194.138.0.25:9400/"
 last line
```